# New method for meta-analysis to determine agreement between multiple sources

Tags: statistical-significance, agreement-statistics

I'm writing a paper on a method to determine the statistical significance of whether a sample of sources are in mutual agreement on specific premises. This is done by counting the number of sources in the sample that agree with the premise, and the number of sources that disagree, and subjecting them to a formula to determine the minimum level of significance.

Please tell me if: (1) a better method already exists to do what I am attempting, (2) if my method seems reasonable, (3) any flaws in my method.

Please bear in mind that the purpose is only to determine mutual agreement, and the result is not a true probability but a minimum probability based on the initial assumptions.

---

In order to develop the formula to be used for calculating statistical significance I defined the logical premises for statistical significance as follows:

1. The statistical significance of a premise representing a single school of thought throughout all sources increases exponentially with each supporting quotation, and is reduced exponentially by each contradicting quotation.
2. The significance is always a decimal number. The closer the value to 1, the more statistically significant.
3. A statement with an equal number of supporting and contradicting quotations will have a significance of 0. Any positive number is an indication of a supporting majority. Absolute certainty is 1, which can never be reached in practice.
4. Considering that there are theoretically an infinite number of possible statements which could be made, the probability of 3 synonymous statements being made in independent sources by chance is virtually zero. Following this logic we can be certain that if there are 3 quotations to support a statement and 0 contradicting quotations then we can be certain of statistical significance. This marks the minimum acceptance level for “statistically significant”, known as the alpha level.
5. I further label “probably significant” as 2 synonymous premises being made in independent sources, with 0 contradicting premises. “Probably significant” premises are considered as not statistically significant, but the label helps to identify those statements that only just missed the mark, which may be useful for more practical purposes.

The formula I developed to match the above premises is as follows:

t = 1-(1/((y^2+ 1)/(x^2+ 1)))

y represents the number of quotations which support the premise; x represents the number of quotations which contradict the premise. The result of t is not a probability in our context, but a value representative of the logical premises on which the formula was based.

The formula calculates that 3 supporting quotations with 0 contradicting quotations has a value of 0.9. Therefore all values above or equal to 0.9 are statistically significant. The formula further calculates that if there is 1 contradicting quotation we would need 5 supporting quotations for it to still be considered at least as statistically significant as 3 supporting quotations would be with 0 contradictory quotations, i.e. with a value greater than or equal to 0.9.
“Probably significant” has a value of 0.8, though I would like to remind the reader that this is still counted as not statistically significant.

It should be noted that if there are 3 or more contradictory quotations to the premise and all the contradictory quotations are in mutual agreement, in addition to there being 3 or more synonymous supporting quotations for the premise, then this would indicate the existence of two different schools of thought on the premise.

The following is a table showing the results of the formula for up to 20 quotations supporting the potential premise (rows) and up to 6 quotations contradicting the potential premise (columns).

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6   Against
0   0.000                            
1   0.500   0.000                        
2   0.800   0.600   0.000                    
3   0.900   0.800   0.500   0.000                
4   0.941   0.882   0.706   0.412   0.000            
5   0.962   0.923   0.808   0.615   0.346   0.000        
6   0.973   0.946   0.865   0.730   0.541   0.297   0.000    
7   0.980   0.960   0.900   0.800   0.660   0.480   0.260    
8   0.985   0.969   0.923   0.846   0.738   0.600   0.431    
9   0.988   0.976   0.939   0.878   0.793   0.683   0.549    
10  0.990   0.980   0.950   0.901   0.832   0.743   0.634    
11  0.992   0.984   0.959   0.918   0.861   0.787   0.697    
12  0.993   0.986   0.966   0.931   0.883   0.821   0.745    
13  0.994   0.988   0.971   0.941   0.900   0.847   0.782    
14  0.995   0.990   0.975   0.949   0.914   0.868   0.812    
15  0.996   0.991   0.978   0.956   0.925   0.885   0.836    
16  0.996   0.992   0.981   0.961   0.934   0.899   0.856    
17  0.997   0.993   0.983   0.966   0.941   0.910   0.872    
18  0.997   0.994   0.985   0.969   0.948   0.920   0.886    
19  0.997   0.994   0.986   0.972   0.953   0.928   0.898    
20  0.998   0.995   0.988   0.975   0.958   0.935   0.908    
For
```

As you can see from the table this is a very strict system: if there are 6 contradicting quotations to a given premise then it requires 20 supporting quotations in order for it to be considered statistically significant that the majority of the sources agree on the premise. This is the case even though the contradicting quotations are not required to be in agreement with each other, whereas the supporting quotations are required to be synonymous.

The results of the study must fit one of the following scenarios:

1. Very few or none of the statements have statistically significant support. (The “null hypothesis”)
   This would prove that there is no agreement.
2. Some of the statements have statistically significant support, but overall this is not statistically significant.
   A little agreement here and there would indicate that there is not a definitive system, or it could mean that the alpha level was too strict.
3. A statistically significant number of statements have statistically significant support in one school only.
   This would prove beyond all reasonable doubt that there is a single definitive system.
4. A statistically significant number of statements have more than one school of statistically significant support.
   This would prove beyond all reasonable doubt that there are multiple school, each possessing its own system.

Comment: Please someone at least tell me `yes it sounds reasonable` or `no, I don't like it`.

Comment: I have too few (or no) experience in this domain to comment the quality of your formulae, but to me it seems very arbitrary. There is an infinity of functions matching your criteria, why this one ?

I have some experience in looking at publication, I think a publication is something too complex to just sum it up to "agree/doesn't agree". I'am thinking about quality of the paper. Would you say that a ground breaking article of someone very famous for his tought has the same value as a copy-pasted article from wikipedia ? You are working on quantities, not quality, I think it is a big flaw.

Comment: Imorin, thank you very much for your comments. In my case I'm attempting only to determine whether the sources are in mutual agreement, not whether the premises are correct and not whether one source is of higher quality than another. In this case, would you say that the paper is still flawed?

Comment: "Mutual agreement" is not a methematical concept, it is difficult to translate it into mathematical domain. I can think of a lots of real world exemple where an analysis based on quantities would be flawed. What if a company pay non scientific people to publish thousands of false study thousands of times ? would this be a second school of tought ? And what if the government can only afford one study/publication ? would there only be the first school of tought ?

Comment: So if your goal is mutual agreement by comparing quantities, a function increasing with y and decreasing with x is the key. That's what you've done. (your choice is still too aritrary, how do you link your function to a minimum probability ?)

If you have another goal, I would suggest to include quality in your study.

Comment: Basically that is correct. I think your concerns are an issue for sample selection, since this formulae is only for determining agreement and it therefore does not need to take the quality into consideration. Agreement between low-quality sources is still agreement. (And I actual intend for this to be used specifically on historical data, but I would like it to be able to be used more widely.)

Comment: What do you think about the fact that the number of sources is not a variable in the formula?

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing Cohen's Kappa.

Comment: Hi @toomuchpj, thank you for your comment! I took a look at Cohen's Kappa but it seems to me that this is a measure of agreement between two sources and all it does is deduct the probability that the outcome may have occurred by chance, to give a modified version of what would otherwise be a straight probability. This is quite different to what I'm attempting to achieve as in my case the questions are all open so there isn't a chance agreement value to deduct. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: @Aladair...Well, as stated it did not seem that "open" when you state "mutual agreement on specific premises". I assumed you knew the premises a priori.